# Print pretty list Python

Tags: python

I have a nasty list in which there are some probabilities.
Inside this list there is a dictionary.
I need to print only the highest probability within this dictionary **for each value**

*This is my list*:

```
[{'VERB': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.4360404322063438e-06, 'backpointer': None}, 
'X': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.35691878703381e-09, 'backpointer': None}, 
'INTJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.7514813523875917e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'CCONJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.6096200766817706e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'PUNCT': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 0.0, 'backpointer': None}, 
'DET': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 5.446148483792262e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'PRON': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.7793656326246081e-06, 'backpointer': None}, 
'ADP': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.566050888811433e-07, 'backpointer': None},
'SCONJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.4776321081702159e-05, 'backpointer': None}}]
```

In this case what I'd like to print in output is:

```
{'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'upos': 'SCONJ', 'prob': 1.4776321081702159e-05, 'backpointer': NONE}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
outuput_dict = dict()
for element in my_list:
    for e in element.values():
        if e['prob'] > e['prob' + 1]:
           output_dict = {'word': e, 'prob': e['prob']}
```

But it's not working.

This is the entire list:

```
[{'VERB': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.4360404322063438e-06, 'backpointer': None}, 
'X': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.35691878703381e-09, 'backpointer': None}, 
'INTJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.7514813523875917e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'CCONJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.6096200766817706e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'PUNCT': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 0.0, 'backpointer': None}, 
'DET': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 5.446148483792262e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'PRON': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.7793656326246081e-06, 'backpointer': None}, 
'ADP': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.566050888811433e-07, 'backpointer': None},
'SCONJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.4776321081702159e-05, 'backpointer': None}},
{'word': 'δὲ', 'VERB': {'word': 'δὲ', 'prob': 3.385314691598631e-11, 'backpointer': 'SCONJ'},
'ADJ': {'word': 'δὲ', 'prob': 1.0218141457581168e-11, 'backpointer': 'SCONJ'}, 
'PART': {'word': 'δὲ', 'prob': 5.355221843863726e-07, 'backpointer': 'SCONJ'}, 
'NOUN': {'word': 'δὲ', 'prob': 1.1639795921244636e-11, 'backpointer': 'SCONJ'}, 
'NUM': {'word': 'δὲ', 'prob': 8.88534039789667e-14, 'backpointer': 'SCONJ'}, 
'ADV': {'word': 'δὲ', 'prob': 1.5616333140156954e-07, 'backpointer': 'SCONJ'}}]
```

Comment: Also it's not working because you can't add the string `'prob'` and the integer `1`. What did you intend to achieve by doing that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 If you read it it's pretty clear. Given a list, I'd like to print just the highest probability inside the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `max` with a custom key function:

```
my_list = [{'VERB': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.4360404322063438e-06, 'backpointer': None}, 
'X': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.35691878703381e-09, 'backpointer': None}, 
'INTJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.7514813523875917e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'CCONJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.6096200766817706e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'PUNCT': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 0.0, 'backpointer': None}, 
'DET': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 5.446148483792262e-07, 'backpointer': None}, 
'PRON': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.7793656326246081e-06, 'backpointer': None}, 
'ADP': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 4.566050888811433e-07, 'backpointer': None},
'SCONJ': {'word': 'ἐπειδὰν', 'prob': 1.4776321081702159e-05, 'backpointer': None}}]

for d in my_list:
    print(max(d.values(), key=lambda x: x["prob"]))
```

Comment: It prints ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: It works for me, are you sure your dict is actually a dict and not a string?

Comment: Yes! I've also printed the output result that I'd like to convert.